# Ajax - multi-lingual pages with forms

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I am trying to understand if the following scenario is possible:

1. a .PHP page that has a form and inputs for the user to submit information
2. The page itself offers several different languages for the user to view it in
3. The user can change languages **but** the form and the inputs retain their values (if the user has added information) - so the page cannot be re-loaded (as it would lose the information)

I think this might be achieved using an Ajax solution but I'd appreciate any thoughts or advice.

Comment: Lots of ways to do this. Ajax not necessary, upload all languages and hide all but the default. Then show different languages when each is selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually want to change the page, so reload might still be the best choice. Otherwise you need to change every string on the page with javascript, which can get tedious.

You can do the reload without loosing the data. Just add the language information to the form and send another parameter to avoid the actual action that would normally happen when you send the form on the php side. Render the page in the new language and insert the transmitted data in the form.